# How to copy Ubuntu from an internal hard disk to new laptop?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-7, backup

I had a dual boot windows 7 Home Premium + Ubuntu laptop whose motherboard suddenly went dead on me. Lets call it old laptop.

Now I have arranged a new laptop. It has a dual boot Windows 7 ultimate + Ubuntu installation. In both laptops Ubuntu is installed on a single partition.

I am allowed to wipe out the Ubuntu installation from the new laptop and install old laptop's copy of Ubuntu. I looked around but didn't find anything on how to do it.

Is there anyway that I can get exact Ubuntu image from the internal hard disk of my old laptop and set it up on the new laptop without doing anything to windows 7 installation on the new laptop?

I need an exact image running because there were a lot many packages installed and development work carried out on my old laptop in the past few months.

Will someone please help me ?

Comment: Here comes Clonezilla!!!

Comment: Thank you @Severus Tux
Would love to know how to use it step by step in my case.
Since the new laptop has been borrowed as a favour I do not want to mess anything for that guy

Comment: @user1197736. Not very clear whether you want to delete ubuntu from the new laptop or not?

Comment: @Ashu I am allowed to delete Ubuntu from the new laptop.
Only concern is to get the exact ubuntu with all the packages and the files from the old laptop running onto the new laptop

Comment: When you say exact Ubuntu - do you mean same version of Ubuntu as in your old laptop?

Comment: @Ashu By exact I mean all files, packages, settings as they were in my laptop. The Ubuntu version doesn't matter.  By the way both laptops have Ubuntu 14.04 if that helps.

Comment: @user1197736.Are both the hardware the same too?

Comment: @Ashu No the hardwares are different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35991/discussion-between-user1197736-and-ashu).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to mount your external drive to the new laptop's Ubuntu and simply copy the stuff from external drive to new Laptop's Ubuntu. Merely moving Ubuntu from one laptop to another is not a good idea(provided both the laptops are different). Linux kernel has lot of driver modules and it won't be working that easily. Best bet to copy the data and applications(from /usr and /opt) of the external drive to new Laptop's Ubuntu's /usr and /opt.

Comment: I saw a lot many threads discussing  kind of similar cases but all of them had a running ubuntu installation on the old machine as well.
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=599599